# DatabaseError: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12154 - Google Colab

Tags: oracle

I am getting the following error when I try to create a connection on google colab to my OracleDB using cx_Oracle:

**DatabaseError: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12154**

I have been following this code to connect my db to google colab:

https://medium.com/@FranckPachot/a-jupyter-notebook-on-google-collab-to-connect-to-the-oracle-cloud-atp-5e88b12282b0

```
! ls -l oracle-instantclient*-basiclite-*.rpm || wget https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/oracle/instantclient/x86_64/getPackage/oracle-instantclient19.3-basiclite-19.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm

! ls -l oracle-instantclient*-sqlplus-*.rpm   || wget https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/oracle/instantclient/x86_64/getPackage/oracle-instantclient19.3-sqlplus-19.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm

! sudo apt-get install alien libaio1

! sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient19.3-basiclite-19.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm

! sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient19.3-sqlplus-19.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm

%env ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/19.3/client64/bin

%env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/19.3/client64/lib

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
```

However, when I run my code:

```
CONN_INFO = {
 'host': 'host_name',
 'port': 'port',
 'user': 'username',
 'psw': 'password',
 'service': 'service_name',
}
CONN_STR = '{user}/{psw}@{host}:{port}/{service}'.format(**CONN_INFO)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(CONN_STR)

print(connection.version)
```

I get the following error:

***DatabaseError: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12154***

---- This code works perfectly fine on my local machine in jupyter notebook.

Can anyone help me figure out why it is not working on Google colab.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORACLE_HOME is *not* the bin directory: '/usr/lib/oracle/19.3/client64/bin'.  If everything else is correct, your ORACLE_HOME should be '/usr/lib/oracle/19.3/client64'.

The proximate cause for 'Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-nnnn' is that ORACLE_HOME is improperly set.  The .msb file that contains the error messages is located in relation to ORACLE_HOME.  So if OH is incorrect, it will not be able to locate the text of the error it is trying to report (ORA-12154) so reports the secondary error 'error whilt trying to retreive text for '.  ORA-12154 is will documented all over the web (I've written about it [here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/troubleshooting-ora-12154/).) and most likely will come back to the same issue of not being able to locate a file because ORACLE_HOME (the starting point for locating said file) is incorrect.

Comment: An incorrect setting of ORACLE_HOME is definitely a problem, but you shouldn't actually set ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client.

Answer (score 0):

Unset ORACLE_HOME since this shouldn't be set with Instant Client. And, as pointed out in the other answer, is it set to the wrong location.  With Instant Client 19c RPMs you shouldn't need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH either, since `ldconfig` should have been run automatically for you.   Read the [installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst).

If you have other Oracle software on this computer then there is a possibility there is a clash of Oracle libraries in the system library search path, so you should install Instant Client ZIP files (which don't run `ldconfig`) instead of the RPMs.

The example Dockerfiles in [Part 1: Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1) show Instant Client install commands, so they may be useful even if you aren't using Docker.